# Add class to Wordpress image <div> HTML elements

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to style the element that goes around images embedded in a post
but as far as I can tell there is no way to automatically add a class to it or target <div>s with an <img> inside only without using jQuery or something.
**And there is another condition that automatically add <div>HTML elements, when embedding two pictures.
Not necessary when embedding one picture**

```
<div class="sideBySide">
 <img src="#" alt="">
 <img src="#" alt="">
</div>
```

I have no clue and solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CSS `:has` selector](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-has-selector/) to style elements that contain a different element.

```
div.sideBySide:has(> img) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

This will style any `div` with the class `sideBySide` only if it contains an `img` element as a *direct* descendant.